# Проблема с передачей данных из таблицы в модальное окно

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Пытаюсь внести данные в модальное окно и никак не выходит. В коде ниже формируется таблица. И соответственно интересует формирование кнопки Delete.

```
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-left">ID</th>
                                    <th class="text-left">First Name</th>
                                    <th class="text-left">Last Name</th>
                                    <th class="text-left">Age</th>
                                    <th class="text-left">Email</th>
                                    <th class="text-left">Role</th>
                                    <th class="text-left">Edit</th>
                                    <th class="text-left">Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="users : ${users}">
                                    <td th:utext="${users.id}">ID</td>
                                    <td th:utext="${users.name}">Name</td>
                                    <td th:utext="${users.lastname}">LastName</td>
                                    <td th:utext="${users.age}">age</td>
                                    <td th:utext="${users.login}">login</td>
                                    <td th:utext="${users.roleSet}"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="text-left">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                    data-target="#ModalUpdate">Edit
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="text-left">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger Delete">Delete
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Код модального окна в котором я хочу отображать поля.

```
<!-- Modal Delete-->
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="Delete_Title">Delete user</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <strong> ID </strong>
                    <br>
                    <input class="text-center" disabled size="50" type="text" id="id" value="">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <strong> First name</strong></label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="text-center" disabled size="50" type="text"
                           th:value=$"users.name">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            </p>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Close
                </button>
```

Скрипт который должен дергать поля из таблицы. И вот тут похоже основные проблемы

```
<script>
    var $editRow = null;

    $(".Delete").click(function (e) {
        $editRow = $(this).closest("tr");

        $("#id").val($editRow.data('id'));
        $("#name").val($editRow.find(".name").text());

        $("#ModalDelete").modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

По факту модальное окно не поднимается вообще.
Получаю следующую ошибку

o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

Answer (score 0):

Замените тег `<div>` на `<dialog>` и открывайте так:

```
$('#ModalDelete')[0].show();
```

или

```
$('#ModalDelete')[0].showModal();
```

```html
<dialog>
<div>
   Тестовый диалог
</div>
<div>
   <button onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').close()">OK</button>
</div>
</dialog>

<button onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').showModal()">Диалог</button>
```

Comment: После замены div на dialog. Кнопки исчезли вообще.
Проблемы все так же сохранились.

использовав         $('#ModalDelete')[0].showModal();  - диалоговое окно все так же не поднимается  :(

При этом у меня 2 кнопки. Одна через скрипт сделана, вторая без скрипта. Та что без скрипта прекрасно работает (правда я не могу объект в нее подтянуть). А вот со скриптом проблемы. Увы

Comment: @DenisFilisov https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog браузер сафари чтоли?

Comment: Браузер Гугл хром.

Comment: @DenisFilisov Ну так в хроме же все работает. Пропробуйте пример. Нажмите на кнопку "Выполнить код". И там проявится результат. Может быть, у вас диалог стоит не в  `<body>`, а гдето глубже, или вы в CSS что-то прописали лишнее...

Comment: Диалог точно в <body>. Пример работает. Я вижу. Но я похоже чего-то не понимаю :(

У меня основная проблема передать объект мой в модальное окно на самом деле.

Comment: У вас жалуется на недопустимый заголовок от браузера. Как пишут коллеги на других ресурсах Это может произойти из-за разбора заголовков HTTPS вместо HTTP. Попробуй: Добавление:
`logging.level.org.springframework.web: trace
logging.level.org.apache: trace`
к вашему *application.properties* и посмотрите, что говорит вам Spring.
Проверьте, есть ли какое-либо действие, которое ссылается на другой ресурс, зашифрованный SSL. Смотрите также: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: недопустимый символ, найденный в имени метода. HTTP имена методов должны быть маркерами.